# Dynamic Floating window by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build a dynamic floating window with close button at corner. Is it possible, and also i want to add some content dynamically into that window.

Please help me.. It should be in javascript.. Better without AJAX..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: AJAX is just a method for sending and retrieving data from the server without reloading the page - though you could use AJAX to get your content, creating a popup has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: You really should ask more specific, we can't really help you without knowing which informations you need.

Answer (score 16):

jQuery UI has an awesome floating window. What's cool about the jQuery UI version is that you can also package it with the UI theme manager, which means less time styling.

Check it out here : [jQuery UI Dialog examples](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html)

All it takes is creating a container (probably a div), and one line of code. Something like this:

```
<div id="example">I'm in a dialog!</div>
$("#example").dialog();
```

Here's the documentation: [jQuery UI Dialog documentation](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 2):

My favourite has always been [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/), which lets you do all sorts of interesting visual things. The new kids on the block use [jquery](http://jquery.com/). One of these two should do the trick for you.

There are lots of samples on both sites that do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a "lightbox" technique. 
Here is a [comparison of many lightbox techniques](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/).

Many exist out there on the web, here are some for jquery and prototype libs:

- Jquery: [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), [Lightbox
  Plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
- Prototype: [Lightbox 2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/),
  [Leightbox](http://www.eight.nl/static/files/leightbox/)

Also, check out the 
[wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)) on lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

take look at fancybox http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0):

Well at the most basic just create a div and inject content by setting innerHTML to an HTML string. Positioning it can be tricky since you have to worry about scrolling and different browsers have different means of controlling this. You may also want to position relative to some originating element in the page which you can do by digging the element and it's position out of the event object your javascript function receives when the originating element is clicked.

Google hover popup - first link is http://www.calcaria.net/javascript/2006/09/javascript-hover-over-html-popup.html

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different libraries out there for making windows.  I have found that Livepipes has a very well rounded and customizable javascript library that includes a window control along with a variety of others. http://livepipe.net/control
One that I haven't used but looks promising, is [prototypeui](http://prototype-ui.com/).  It is based on the prototype and scriptaculous javascript libraries. [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) is another I have used that is based on JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There are many events {`mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup`, `click`} that need to be handled, as well as states {`isDragging`, `currentX`, ...} that need to be recorded.

Fortunately, now there are [web components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components) available, so you only need to do it once, and you can use them everywhere.

```html
<button onclick="(()=>document.querySelector('#info-panel').toggle())()">Info</button>
<button onclick="(()=>document.querySelector('#prop-panel').toggle())()">Property</button>
<float-window id="info-panel" width="300" height="200">
  <span slot="header">Info</span>
  Hello world
</float-window>

<float-window id="prop-panel" width="300" height="200">
  <span slot="header">Property</span>
  <dl>
    <dt>Size</dt>
    <dd>Width</dd>
    <dd>Height</dd>
  </dl>
</float-window>

<script>
  class FloatWindow extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        .window {
          position: absolute;
          background-color: white;
          border: 1px solid gray;
          box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          display: none;
        }

        .titleBar {
          background-color: lightgray;
          padding: 5px;
          cursor: move;
        }

        .closeBtn {
          float: right;
          cursor: pointer;
        }

      </style>
      <div class="window">
        <div class="titleBar">
          <span class="title"><slot name="header"></slot></span>
          <span class="closeBtn">×</span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    `

      this.window = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.window')
      this.window.style.width = this.getAttribute("width")
      this.window.style.height = this.getAttribute("height")
      this.titleBar = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.titleBar')
      this.closeBtn = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.closeBtn')
      this.content = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.content')

      this.mouseDownX = 0
      this.mouseDownY = 0
      this.translateX = 0
      this.translateY = 0

      // for resize use
      this._width = 0
      this._height = 0

      this.titleBar.addEventListener('mousedown', this.dragStart.bind(this))
      this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this))

      this.window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.updateCursor.bind(this))

      // resize
      this.window.addEventListener('mousedown', (e)=>{
        if (this.window.style.cursor.includes("resize")) {
          this.mouseDownX = e.clientX
          this.mouseDownY = e.clientY
          this._width = this.window.offsetWidth
          this._height = this.window.offsetHeight
          const handler = this.resizeHandler.bind(this)
          document.addEventListener('mousemove', handler)
          document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler)
          }, {once: true})
        }
      })
    }

    open() {
      this.window.style.display = 'block'
    }

    close() {
      this.window.style.display = 'none'
    }

    toggle() {
      const display = this.window.style.display
      display === '' || display === 'none' ? this.open() : this.close()
    }

    dragStart(e) {
      const m = this.window.style.transform.match(/translate\((-?\d*\.?\d+)px, (-?\d*\.?\d+)px\)/)
      if (m) {
        this.translateX = Number(m[1])
        this.translateY = Number(m[2])
      }
      this.translateX = e.clientX - this.translateX
      this.translateY = e.clientY - this.translateY
      const handler = this.drag.bind(this)
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', handler)
      document.addEventListener('mouseup',
        () => document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handler),
        {once: true}
      )
    }

    drag(e) {
      const x = e.clientX - this.translateX
      const y = e.clientY - this.translateY
      this.window.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
    }

    updateCursor(e) {
      const threshold = 10
      const isNearBottom = (this.window.offsetHeight - e.offsetY) < threshold
      const isNearLeft = e.offsetX < threshold
      const isNearRight = (this.window.offsetWidth - e.offsetX) < threshold
      if (isNearBottom && isNearLeft) {
        this.window.style.cursor = "ne-resize"
      } else if (isNearBottom && isNearRight) {
        this.window.style.cursor = "nw-resize"
      } else if (isNearLeft || isNearRight) {
        this.window.style.cursor = 'col-resize'
      } else if (isNearBottom) {
        this.window.style.cursor = 'row-resize'
      } else {
        this.window.style.cursor = 'initial'
      }
    }

    resizeHandler(e) {
      let [dx, dy] = [0, 0]
      switch (this.window.style.cursor) {
        case 'row-resize':
          dy = e.clientY - this.mouseDownY
          break
        case 'col-resize':
          dx = e.clientX - this.mouseDownX
          break
        default:
          dy = e.clientY - this.mouseDownY
          dx = e.clientX - this.mouseDownX
      }

      this.window.style.width = `${this._width + dx}px`
      this.window.style.height = `${this._height + dy}px`
    }
  }

  customElements.define('float-window', FloatWindow)

  const floatWindow = document.querySelector('float-window')
  floatWindow.open()
</script>
```